# Variance of ordered card picking question (without replacement)

Tags: probability, variance, covariance

The question is as followed: Suppose n cards - numbered 1,2,...,n are shuffled and kept faced down, and we suppose the cards are turned over 1-by-1. Define $X_i$ to be:

1 if the i-th card card is turned over at the i-th stage 
0 otherwise

We're told N = $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i}$. Find E(N) and Var(N).

---

Through conditional probabilities, I find the P($X_i$=1) is 1/n for all I, which leads us to an E(N) = $1/n*n$ = 1

I'm not sure how to approach the covariance part of the variance? Any hints?

Comment: Recall that $\text{Var}(N) = E[N^2] - E[N]^2$.  Consider how you can calculate $N^2$ and $E[N^2]$ and recall how multiplying two binary random variables works.

Comment: This step is fine, but the dependance of Xi on Xj (s.t. i != j) leads to a lingering covariance term, which I'm not sure how to approach

Comment: $E[X_iX_i] = E[X_i]$ since $1\times 1 = 1$ and $0\times 0=0$.  On the other hand with $i\neq j$ you have $E[X_iX_j] = \Pr(X_i=1\wedge X_j=1) = \Pr(X_1\wedge X_2)$ is the probability the first card is specifically the $1$ and the second card is specifically the $2$.  Do you know how to find that probability?

Comment: @JMoravitz I computed this probability to be (1/(n^2-n)) which implies the expectation is also that. Then there are n^2 - n covariances which (s.t. i != j). So all in all I got the covariance portion to be (n^2-n)*(1/(n^2-n)-1/n^2) i.e. (# of coveriances)*(E(XiXj) - E(Xi)E(Xj))

Comment: Sounds good and that you are on the way to finishing the problem.

Comment: @JMoravitz After finishing the computation, I get the variance of this to be = 1 (because the non-covariance term is 1 - (1/n). Adding the covariance we get Var(N) = 1. What Im finding difficult to explain is why the Var(N) is bigger in this scenario (without replacement) than it would be with replacement. In the case of with replacement there is no covariance term hence the variance is simple 1-(1/n) (lower than without replacement). Why? Would the value of N vary less when the terms are correlated compared to when they are not?

Comment: "*Why*"  I should think the work you have done here explains that part already.  $\text{Var}(N)=1$ is correct, and so too is the result of $1-\frac{1}{n}$ in the case of with replacement.  I can't help much to explain the intuition behind this result beyond pointing you to small examples.  In the case of $n=2$ if you do this without replacement you will either have $0$ fixed points or $2$ fixed points, but if you did with replacement you will have $0,1,$ or $2$ fixed points.  In both cases the mean is the same.  It seems clear to me why at least in this case, the variance is more for without.